# Duvida, erro haskell

Tags: programação-funcional, haskell

Eu quero somar os valores de uma lista de listas em haskell usando a função map, mas da erro. Erro de tipo

```
gastoEmpresa :: [[Float]] -> Float
gastoEmpresa xss = map(map sum xss)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

O tipo da função `map` é

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

i.e., `map` é uma função recebe como parâmetros uma função (de `a` para `b`) e uma lista de tipo `a` e retorna uma lista de tipo `b`.

Sabendo isto, fica fácil perceber a razão da mensagem de erro. Na sua segunda aplicação, `map` recebe menos argumentos/parâmetros que o esperado (map is applied to too few arguments).

Vamos primeiro, remover a segunda aplicação da função `map` e ver o resultado parcial.

Seja `l` a lista `[[1, 4], [2, 3]]`, o resultado de `map sum l` é

`[5, 5]`

Conseguimos assim, criar uma lista em que cada elemento resulta do somatório dos elementos das sub-listas. O que necessitamos agora, não é aplicar a função map pela segunda vez, mas sim apenas de uma função que receba uma lista e retorne o somatório de todos os seus elementos: a função `sum`

Juntando tudo, uma implementação possível seria:

```
gastoEmpresa :: [[Float]] -> Float
gastoEmpresa l = sum ( map sum l )
```

Ou no estilo pointfree:

```
gastoEmpresa :: [[Float]] -> Float
gastoEmpresa = sum . map sum
```